# How do I prohibit access to one of my folders with .htaccess? [Ubuntu]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I am running a DigitalOcean droplet with Ubuntu 14.04 x64.

In my `/var/www/html` directory, I have a `include/` folder of files I include in PHP files but aren't standalone. I would like to prohibit direct URL access (return 403 errors) to these files, but still make it so that my standalone files can include them.

I have tried creating a .htaccess file inside the `include/` folder containing:

```
<Files *>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
    Allow From {my droplet IP address}
</Files>
```

This is not prohibiting access. Is this the right approach? Is my `.htaccess` file wrong? Is the IP address I am allowing from wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: 1. You probably want to remove the "<Files>" tags. 

2. The "Order" should be the other way around. See e.g. http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess.php

3. Are you sure that you need an "Allow" rule in the first place? You can access the folder via (s)ftp/ssh/... anyway to administrate your files and include them into php in other (accessible) folders. If you do not need the Allow rule, a one-line .htaccess file with "Deny from all" will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess prohibits access from your Apache web server to files loaded by HTML, primarily CSS and JavaScript files. It has no effect on PHP Include because PHP has unrestricted server-side access to your file system. PHP does not itself call Apache to load files, so it does not honor .htaccess files. This is the main security problem with PHP: there is no easy way to prevent remote servers from loading or including files from your server if the remote server PHP.ini file permits this.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried Options -Indexes
Create an .htaccess file with that content and place it inside the folder.

Comment: Can you please clarify? Should I add that to my existing `.htaccess` file?

Comment: to deny the access to that directory just create a .htaccess with that content. Just remember to make a backup of proceeding with the changes.

Comment: No, that does NOT prohibit acces to the files inside the directory, it just disables indexing (as would putting an empty index.html as suggested below)
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options